# C++ program will not compile without including function list

Tags: c++, class, compilation, header, include

I have 3 files, main.cpp, Graphics.cpp and Graphics.h. The function definitions are in Graphics.h. The functions are in Graphics.cpp. The main program is in main.cpp. The code compiles fine, but will not build.

when I run

```
$ g++ -Wall -o "main" "main.cpp" -lSDL -lSDL_image -lSDL_mixer -lSDL_ttf               
/tmp/cce3Gqez.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xfd): undefined reference to `Graphics::clear(int, int, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x207): undefined reference to `Graphics::drawPixel(int, int, int, int, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x364): undefined reference to `Graphics::drawRect(int, int, int, int, int, int, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4b7): undefined reference to `Graphics::fillRect(int, int, int, int, int, int, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4c5): undefined reference to `Graphics::flip()'
/tmp/cce3Gqez.o: In function `InitProgram()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x54f): undefined reference to `Graphics::init(int, int, bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

the reffrences to functions arent recognized?
when I include "#include "Graphics.cpp" " in the top of main.cpp, the program runs properly. I'm sure that this is improper to do, but I cant get it to work any other way.
 here are the 3 source files:

```
#include "Graphics.h"
//#include "Graphics.cpp"

const int FPS = 30;
const int FRAME_TIME = 1000/FPS;
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
const int FULLSCREEN = false;

Graphics graphics;

bool InitProgram();
void FreeProgram();
bool ProgramRunning();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(!InitProgram())
    {
        FreeProgram();
        return false;
    }

    int counter = 0;

    while(ProgramRunning())
    {
        int frameStart = SDL_GetTicks();

        counter++;

        if(counter > 90)
        {
            counter = 0;
            graphics.clear(rand()%255, rand()%255, rand()%255);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            graphics.drawPixel(rand()%SCREEN_WIDTH, rand()%SCREEN_HEIGHT, rand()%255, rand()%255, rand()%255);

        graphics.drawRect(rand()%SCREEN_WIDTH, rand()%SCREEN_HEIGHT, rand()%100, rand()%100, rand()%255, rand()%255, rand()%255);
        graphics.fillRect(rand()%SCREEN_WIDTH, rand()%SCREEN_HEIGHT, rand()%100, rand()%100, rand()%255, rand()%255, rand()%255);

        graphics.flip();

        int frameTime = SDL_GetTicks()-frameStart;
        int delay = FRAME_TIME - frameTime;

        if(delay > 0)
            SDL_Delay(delay);
    }

    FreeProgram();

    return 0;
}

bool InitProgram()
{
    if(SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1)
        return false;

    if(!graphics.init(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, FULLSCREEN))
        return false;

    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Graphics Test", NULL);

    return true;
}

void FreeProgram()
{
    SDL_Quit();
}

bool ProgramRunning()
{
    SDL_Event event;

    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

what can I do to make this compile properly? Am I missing linker flags? I am using g++ and I am new to writing header files.what is the right way to compile main.cpp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the preprocessor to `#include` a cpp source file (`*.cpp`).

You will have to **link** `Graphics.cpp` or object file compiled from it instead.

Try this:

```
$ g++ -Wall -o "main" "main.cpp" "Graphics.cpp" -lSDL -lSDL_image -lSDL_mixer -lSDL_ttf
```

Comment: Hey, what if I have multiple cpp files?

Comment: Link all needed source or object files.